# Horizontal aceleration in parabolic motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

Which is the proof that the $a_x = 0 $ in parabolic motion?

having an initial velocity V, by the Newton law  $m*a_x = V*cos(\theta)$

so $ a_x = V*cos(\theta) / m$

Comment: Why do you think $V\cos\theta$ is a force, instead of a velocity component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's Laws, particularly the second one states that (for constant mass):

$$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$$

In your example you assume that gravity is vertical at all times, which means basically you assume a flat earth or said differently you assume that your distances are much smaller than the earth's radius. If gravity is vertical (let's call it in y-direction), the only force acting on the mass is in y direction and consequently the other components (x and z) of the force and (by above equation) of the acceleration are zero.

Comment: i undestand now. the velocity is not considered like a force!

Comment: @RobertNN Not sure what you mean by this, but glad it helped.

Comment: i mean that. Why dont you use de Velocity_x component to horizontal aceleration?

Comment: @RobertNN: I suspect that you misunderstand Newton's equation.  It is not like you take an acceleration from somewhere and this gives you a force, but rather the other way around. You have a force (here gravity) acting on your system and this causes it to accelerate. As you can see from the equation the direction of the force and the acceleration are the same. If you have only a force in vertical direction you will only get acceleration in that direction.

Comment: @user1593209 let me know if i understand correctly now... The velocity vector is not a force (that change acceleration), it just a initial condition of my system?

Comment: The velocity is a velocity, not a force.  The velocity vector just tells you speed and direction of the object at all times, not only as initial condition. The rate of change (time derivative) of the velocity vector is the acceleration that appears in Newton's law. There is only one force in your model which is gravity. Gravity acts vertically and (by  Newton's second law) makes the object accelerate in the vertical direction.

Comment: The $V$ in your equations is a scalar, equal to the initial velocity of the object. $V\cos\theta$ (where $\theta$ is the angle to the horizontal at which you throw),  is the x-component of the initial velocity (which stays constant because there is no force acting in x-direction.

Comment: yes yes its the thing that i undestand. I speak spanish so my english is not very well. I will give you the accepted answerd Thanks a lot friend!

Answer (score 1):

[Here you will find](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html#tra12) the solution of trajectories of an object due to gravity:

> The motion of an object under the influence of gravity is determined completely by the acceleration of gravity, its launch speed, and launch angle provided air friction is negligible. The horizontal and vertical motions may be separated and described by the [general motion equations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mot.html#mot1) for constant acceleration. The initial vector components of the velocity are used in the equations. The diagram shows trajectories with the same launch speed but different launch angles. Note that the 60 and 30 degree trajectories have the same range, as do any pair of launches at complementary angles. The launch at 45 degrees gives the maximum range.

As you see there is horizontal motion , constant velocity as a function of time. The vertical velocity is time depenent as expected.

[image: trajectories]

addition after comment

> Which is the proof that the $a_x=0$ in parabolic motion?

There is no acceleration/deceleration in the horizontal direction (ignoring friction ), no force acting there to give F=ma. Gravitational force is vertical, to first approximation. The initial impulse separates the velocity components into a horizontal , no acceleration, and a vertical component.

Comment: i cannot undestand why a_x is 0. Velocity vector is not considered in m*a_x equation?

Comment: horizontal motion has no acceleration, i.e. change dv_x/dt. A single  vector is  is given to initiate the throw   that will make the trajectory. this is vectorially split  into v_x and v_y. The v_y undergoes deceleration and then again acceleration  , the v_x is constant.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @user1583209  There is no acceleration/deceleration  in the horizontal direction (ignoring friction ), no force acting there to  give F=ma. Gravitational force is   vertical, to first approximation. The initial impulse separates the velocity components  into a horizontal , no acceleration, and a vertical.

Comment: @annav: I understand that and answered the question basically like this. I think you should add this comment to your answer as currently your answer does not seem to answer the original question (why $a_x=0$?) or the answer is hidden in the linked website.